# Building a build server on an Atom Mini-ITX PC

Tags: linux, windows, virtualization, build-server

I am planning on turning my 1.6Ghz Atom, 1GB RAM Mini-ITX PC into a build machine.  I am thinking about having it build for multiple environments, so I was planning on using Virtual Box to create a VM environment.

Will my machine handle multiple VMs? How many should I max at?
Should I use Linux as the host and have XP as a guest or should I use XP as the host and have CC.Net run on the host (I only want to use one license of XP)?
I plan to host my SVN repositories in its own VM, does that make sense?

I will post more questions as I think of them or as they become relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I advise against using an Intel Atom CPU for this kind of work for its lack of [out-of-order execution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution).

If you really want to use that machine, you should not use virtualization techniques and expect low performance. If you have the time, run tests with your expected workload.

Comment: Do you suggest that I just set it up as a single os box, no VM, and use my build server software of choice?

Comment: I updated my response accordingly.

Comment: I'm not expecting this PC to scream, its a spare computer I have laying around and I have some software projects that I am currently working on, and figured I would build a build server for them

Comment: Agreed. Atom CPU is not built for this purpose. Don't try to use it out of context. Yes, power savings are a good thing, but there are better CPUs/systems for this precise type of work.

Answer (score 1):

If your not after too much performance then it should be suitable, I would however recommend upgrading your memory to a little higher.  1GB is a little on the low side, increasing it to 2GB or even 3GB will make a heap of difference.

I would also have the SVN running on the host as if it is running in a VM you need to have the host and VM running.

With the current RAM configuration, you would only be able to run 1 VM, with more RAM you could run 3 or 4 VM at the same time.  Keep in mind drive space, the more VMs you have setup the more space you require.

Comment: It may have 2GB of RAM, I don't remember what it has, I do know that it maxes at 2GB

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my server: http://howto.basjes.nl/linux/installing-my-new-server

I have it running under CentOS 5.3 64bit with VMware Server and 2 VM's (also running CentOS 5.3 64 bit). I have Vlans configured, firewall, etc.
I also have an ISDN card in ti and it also serves as our home Asterisk box which allows (free of charge) VOIP calling with our family.

Works like a charm for our home purposes.